# What creates ~/.bashrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bashrc

I am setting up a ubuntu web server. Id like to customize everyones bash prompt a bit. (As in $PS1) Editing /etc/bash.bashrc doesn't seem to work, I assume cause ~/.bashrc over writes it. The question is, when a new user is made, what creates its .bashrc? I would like every user of this system to have the same prompt.

Server is Ubuntu Server 10.4 LTS

Thanks,
Russell "TheDigitalNinja" Perkins

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's copied from `/etc/skel/.bashrc` for new users

Comment: Thanks so much, I wouldn't have ever found that on my own. Googleing anything with .bashrc gets less than useful results.

Comment: No problem, just remember it won't update existing .bashrc files - only create new ones for new users.